# GDB MI mechanism to debug a self executing program

Tags: c, gdb, gdbserver

I recently downloaded MI library and executed / read some examples code. In all the examples that I saw the implementation was via a separate program like below:

```
Main Program
Interact with GDB
exec another program
Gather  Debug info of the another program
```

My question is how can we invoke / implement GDB within current thread/program itself i.e. attach this self-execution process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can we invoke / implement GDB MI within current thread/program itself i.e. attach this self-execution/ running process to GDB and then tell it to execute step by step

You can't.

Think about it: the very first thing GDB will do after attaching is *stop* your program, and wait for instructions on what to do next. At that point your program should send GDB the `continue` command, except it *can't* because it has been *stopped*.

Now, *if* your program is multi-threaded, *and* you ask GDB to execute in non-stop mode, *and* you carefully arrange things such that your thread that performs GDB interaction itself is never stopped, then *perhaps* this could work. I doubt it will work reliably though.

Comment: But in GDB we can attach / detach a process using its PID. Is there no way we can achieve that here?

Comment: @Prakash "But in GDB we can attach / detach a process using its PID" -- this comment indicates that you didn't understand my answer. I (again) advise you to *think* about it.

Comment: @Employed Russian, why the non-stop mode won't work reliably? I want to use it in the unit tests for the multithreaded code (to wait until other thread enters the function, for example). It will replace a really intrusive mutex/cond-var test harness.